# Ionic 2: Android: TypeError: Property ‘jscomp_symbol_iterator0’ of object [object Array] is not a function

Tags: javascript, android, ionic2

I am working in basic Ionic 2 app with Firebase integration.

Code is working great in Browser. But in Android, I am getting this error.

```
EXCEPTION: Error in build/pages/home/home.html:17:37 browser_adapter.js:77
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Property 'jscomp_symbol_iterator0' of object [object Array] is not a function browser_adapter.js:77
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE: browser_adapter.js:77
TypeError: Property 'jscomp_symbol_iterator0' of object [object Array] is not a function
at Object.areIterablesEqual (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:1718:50)
at Object.devModeEqual (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:24603:29)
at checkBinding (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:30678:33)
at DebugAppView._View_HomePage0.detectChangesInternal (HomePage.template.js:197:7)
at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:30083:14)
at DebugAppView.detectChanges (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:30188:44)
at DebugAppView.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:30109:19)
at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChangesInternal (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:30094:14)
at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:30083:14)
at DebugAppView.detectChanges (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:30188:44)
```

Here is my home/home.html. It looks all fine:

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar primary>

    <ion-title>SO Login</ion-title>

    <ion-buttons end>
        <button id="create" (click)='newOrder($event)'>
            <ion-icon id="cr" light name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>

</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding class="home">
<ion-list> // Line 17
    <button ion-item detail-none *ngFor="let order of orderList" (click)='orderSelected(order)'>
        {{order.customerName}}
    </button>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Line 17 as specifed in the Error, refers to the line with the tag

Not sure what's wrong with it. Please help.

My Ionic Info:

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.1.0 (cordova-lib@undefined)
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.10
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.32
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.18
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.6 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v4.2.6
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2 Build version 7C68
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would need to see all the code, but please check the order you load scripts (probably index.html); make sure you've added

```
 es6-shim.min.js
 Reflect.js
 zone.js
```

before `3.1.0/firebase.js`